# Multiple switch statement with conditional inside

Tags: swift, switch-statement

Is there a cleaner way of writing the conditional for case "1", "4", "7"? For this case I want to write to the string "b" only if the string value is not "4".

```
var b = ""
var c = ""

let s = "4"

switch s {
case "0", "6", "8":
    c += "|_|"
case "1", "4", "7":
    if s != "4" { b += "  |" }
    c += "  |"
case "2":
    c += "|_ "
case "3", "5", "9":
    c += " _|"
default:
    c += ""
}
```

Comment: I would put "4" in its own case to avoid the `if`, that would at least be a bit cleaner imo. and also do `default: break` instead of updating `c`

Comment: Cleaner may have been the wrong word. I know in practice it would be good to write things readably, but I want them more compressed.

Answer (score 4):

This is a place you could use the [`fallthrough`](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID135) statement:

```
switch s {
case "0", "6", "8":
    c += "|_|"
case "1", "7":
    b += "  |"
    fallthrough
case "4":
    c += "  |"
case "2":
    c += "|_ "
case "3", "5", "9":
    c += " _|"
default:
    break
}
```

Since you want `"1"` and `"7"` to execute both statements, give them their own case and then follow it with `fallthough` which allows it to fall though to the next case.  Then `"1"`, `"4"`, and `"7"` will all execute the code in the `case "4":` case.

Comment: Using fallthrough seems like the best solution. (Voted.)

Answer (score 2):

I think the whole idea of switch statement is that you don’t use ifs inside. You should probably just create a separate case for “4”. The amount of space saved by putting this conditional isn’t worth obscuring the code IMO.